# How to retrieve data from the internet on ios app launch with slow connections

Tags: ios

I'm working on an app that retrieves some information from the internet on launch. The code is in didFinishLaunchWithOptions. Everything is fine with wifi or 3G connections but with slower connections the app crashes. I know the reason: iOS kill the apps that take more than 20 seconds to finish didFinishLaunchWithOptions.

The question is which is the correct approach to solve this situation? Some example?

Thanks a lot,

Carlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple Human Interface Guidelines a splash screen shouldn't be shown for a long time, it's expected to bring the user a better experience with quickly loading application.

So, what does it mean ? It means that you should not put any heavy logic at didFinishLaunchWithOptions, instead put it at your root view controller and show user some interface, as've been already suggested async connection doesn't block the application while the data is loaded. That way you may (and should) allow a user to play a little with the interface. Caching is highly recommended, especially in your case - use it if only possible.

Comment: So, should I retrieve the data on the rootViewController's ViewDidLoad? Is it the correct method to do it? On the other hand in my case I think is better to block the app (with some activity indicator) because I'm getting the data that the app must show, so I can't show anything if I don't have the data... Thanks!!

Comment: The best practice from my experience is to prepare as much basic UI at didLoad as possible, and all the connectivity starts with didAppear. It gives you fast and responsible interface. There's a good example - native YouTube app. launch it, play a little and try to imagine, that it tries to load all the data for all the tabs while launching. Impressive, isn't it ? And now press Load More in the bottom of the videos list - you can play with the app while it's working for you. Try to bring the user as good experience as you can :) Even a simple activity indicator would be fine for the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot, tomorrow morning I will try to follow your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Use Asynchronous calls
Check out http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Note that ASIHTTPRequest is out of date and not in development anymore (i.e. no ARC-support). Consider using AFNetworking or similar frameworks instead.

Comment: That project is no longer active (Last updated: 15th May 2011 (v1.8.1)). If you want to know why it is no longer maintained or what to use now see here http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. Didn't touch that stuff for a while. Asynchronous requests is still the way.